# Using curl -s in *nix command line not working for some reason

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, curl

I am trying to install composer (though to be honest I really have no idea how it fully works and documentation seems to be quite poor) on my MediaTemple DV machine. I am using their [instructions](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Trying to install globally using:

```
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

My command line (again using putty and logged into my server as root) thinks for a second, then sets up for next prompt. I run a simple ls -l  to check for the file it should have downloaded with no luck.

Any idea what could be causing the issue? I have tested and do in fact have curl installed.

### UPDATE 1

Based on the first answer, the verbose response is:

```
$ curl -vs https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
* About to connect() to getcomposer.org port 443
*   Trying 37.59.4.156... connected
* Connected to getcomposer.org (37.59.4.156) port 443
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
* SSLv2, Client hello (1): SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2): SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11): SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12): SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14): SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16): SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20): SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20): SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: /C=CH/CN=dl.packagist.org/emailAddress=x6g02fqayn7d1itqtw2t@a.o-w-o.info
*        start date: 2012-07-07 23:25:35 GMT
*        expire date: 2013-07-10 02:55:12 GMT
* SSL: certificate subject name 'dl.packagist.org' does not match target host name 'getcomposer.org'
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing curl in verbose mode (-v):

```
curl -vs https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: posting code above based on your response.

Comment: there's a problem with SSL certificate, add -k to curl to allow connections to SSL sites without certs

Comment: I'm assuming somebody saw this on their end because I just tried a second time and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I ran into this same problem and adding -k worked for me.